# How to store elements in boost::multi_index::multi_index_container?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I want to use multi index container of boost. To use it I tried following sample program to understand the insertion of elements in the container.

Following is my code :

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include "boost/multi_index/global_fun.hpp"
#include "boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp"
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include "boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp"
#include "boost/multi_index/member.hpp"
#include "boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp"

using namespace std;

class uri
{
  public:
        string str;
        uri(string s):str(s)
        {
        }
        string getUri(){ return str; }

};


struct UriWithBase
{
  UriWithBase(uri u1, uri u2):link(u1), baseLink(u2){}
  uri link;
  uri baseLink;
};



int main()
{
  typedef boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<
     UriWithBase*,
     boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
        boost::multi_index::sequenced<>
     > 
 > UriMultiIndex;

  UriMultiIndex m_uris;

  uri urib1("www.google.com");
  uri uri1("www.news.google.com");

  UriWithBase *ubptr = new UriWithBase(uri1, urib1);

  m_uris.insert(ubptr);
  return 0;
}
```

However when I compiled the following it shows following error:

```
main.cc: In function `int main()':
main.cc:67: error: no matching function for call to `boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<UriWithBase*, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::sequenced<boost::multi_index::tag<mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na> >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::allocator<UriWithBase*> >::insert(UriWithBase*&)'

../include/boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp:304: note: candidates are: std::pair<boost::multi_index::detail::bidir_node_iterator<boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<typename SuperMeta::type::node_type> >, bool> boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index<SuperMeta, TagList>::insert(boost::multi_index::detail::bidir_node_iterator<boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<typename SuperMeta::type::node_type> >, const typename boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<typename SuperMeta::type::node_type>::value_type&) [with SuperMeta = boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<1, UriWithBase*, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::sequenced<boost::multi_index::tag<mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na> >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::allocator<UriWithBase*> >, TagList = boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na>]
    ../include/boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp:316: note:                 std::pair<boost::multi_index::detail::bidir_node_iterator<boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<typename SuperMeta::type::node_type> >, bool> boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index<SuperMeta, TagList>::insert(boost::multi_index::detail::bidir_node_iterator<boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<typename SuperMeta::type::node_type> >, boost::rv<typename boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<typename SuperMeta::type::node_type>::value_type>&) [with SuperMeta = boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<1, UriWithBase*, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::sequenced<boost::multi_index::tag<mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na> >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::allocator<UriWithBase*> >, TagList = boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na>]
    ../include/boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp:328: note:                 void boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index<SuperMeta, TagList>::insert(boost::multi_index::detail::bidir_node_iterator<boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<typename SuperMeta::type::node_type> >, size_t, typename boost::call_traits<typename boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<typename SuperMeta::type::node_type>::value_type>::param_type) [with SuperMeta = boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<1, UriWithBase*, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::sequenced<boost::multi_index::tag<mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na> >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::allocator<UriWithBase*> >, TagList = boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na>]
```

Any pointer to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#seq_indices) says

> The interface of sequenced indices is thus designed upon that of
>   std::list; nearly every operation provided in the standard container
>   is replicated here...

Thus the `insert` method requires two parameters. Using the `push_back` and `push_front` methods required one parameter - a reference to the value. Below is the compilable code

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include "boost/multi_index/global_fun.hpp"
#include "boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp"
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include "boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp"
#include "boost/multi_index/member.hpp"
#include "boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp"
#include "boost/multi_index/indexed_by.hpp"

using namespace std;

class uri
{
public:
    string str;
    uri(string s) :str(s)
    {
    }
    string getUri(){ return str; }

};


struct UriWithBase
{
    UriWithBase(uri u1, uri u2) :link(u1), baseLink(u2){}
    uri link;
    uri baseLink;
};



int main()
{
    typedef boost::multi_index::multi_index_container <
        UriWithBase*,
        boost::multi_index::indexed_by <
        boost::multi_index::sequenced < >
        >
    > UriMultiIndex;

    UriMultiIndex m_uris;

    uri urib1("www.google.com");
    uri uri1("www.news.google.com");

    UriWithBase *ubptr = new UriWithBase(uri1, urib1);

    m_uris.push_back(ubptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @megabyte2014 thanks you for answer it worked very well.
Could you please tell me how typedef should be declared to check insert status. I tried following but didn't worked
typedef std::pair<UriMultiIndex::index<boost::multi_index::sequenced>::type::iterator, bool>  InsertStatus;

Comment: @BSalunke, It is `std::pair<UriMultiIndex::iterator, bool> prRes = m_uris.push_back(ubptr);`, but I prefer `auto prRes = ....`

Comment: @megabyte2014 Thanks it worked, However I found one more problem :( Now I'm trying to add another index specifier in the multi index container that add the elements uniquely ordered for the first element of "UriWithBase" class i.e. link. How index specifier would be, I tried following but didn't worked
boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<                                            boost::multi_index::tag<tab_name>,                                             BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CONST_MEM_FUN(UriWithBasePtr, const uri&, (*(UriWithBasePtr)).link)>

Comment: @BSalunke, My opinion is that your last question, does not relate to the title and it is better to create a new topic for it. BTW, I see a memory leak in the code, the `ubptr` object will be not deleted when the `m_uris` instance is deleted. A solution is to pass UriWithBase by value, i.e. `m_uris.push_back(UriWithBase(uri1, urib1));` or to wrap the `ubptr` pointer to a smart pointer. For sure in both cases the `UriMultiIndex` declaration will be changed.

Comment: added new thread for last question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255152/how-to-add-the-ordered-unique-index-specifies-in-multi-index-container

Answer (score 1):

You need an insertion hint here:

```
m_uris.insert(m_uris.end(), ubptr);
```

<sub>Oh, and here's a pointer: `nullptr` :)</sub>